# Адаптивная верстка DIV

Tags: css, адаптивная-верстка

Есть страница на сайте https://finansanswer.ru/mikrozajmy/na-kartu-sberbanka/, на которой есть `div` с предложением микрозаймов.

Вопрос: что мне нужно в таблицу стилей прописать, чтобы верстка была адаптивной и на мобильных устройствах, к примеру, как здесь: allzaims.ru/karta-sberbanka/?
Я так понимаю - какие-то ограничения для расширения экрана.

Буду благодарен, если покажите пример того, что нужно сделать. 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропишите желаемый размер для нужного `div` в медиа-запросах нужного размера, например:

```
/* для экранов в 992px или меньше */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .mydiv {
    max-width: 300px /*или в процентах, например*/
 /* или так, например:
     .mydiv {
width: 100%;
min-width: 100px;
max-width: 300px;
   }  */
  }
}

/* для экранов в  600px или меньше*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .mydiv {
    max-width: 100px /*или в процентах, например*/
  }
}
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что мне нужно задать ограничение под экраны и для них специально новые стили создать, так как старые под десктоп?

Comment: У Вас сайт на ВП - найдите в стилях соответствующие блоки/блок и добавьте туда. Или отдельно пропишите медиа именно для этого блока - обратите внимание, чтобы они не перебивались существующими, если идентификатор нужного div используется где-то еще. И у Вас уже адаптив (сайт по ссылке) - поэтому, там все нужное есть.

Comment: Да это для меня темный лес, кодить на php и python научился, а вот стили так и не освоил :(

Comment: Не расстраивайтесь - просто начните и попробуйте - и все  у Вас получится.